# Improve edit-run cycle time on .Net Core

Tags: f#, .net-core, rider, paket, logary

I'm trying to improve the performance in Logary and am bumping into an unexpected issue with .Net Core; even a single-character change in Logary.PerfTests

[image]

causes a complete restore throughout all of the repository (I think), with this as a result:

[image: Paket eating my CPU]

Can I somehow improve the change-run performance? I've tried the core-only sln file, but dotnet core/rider seems to restore all nugets for all projects no matter.

Here's paket.dependencies for the group:

```
group Benchmarks
    source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    framework net471, netcoreapp2.0
    redirects on
    nuget FParsec
    nuget FSharp.Core
    nuget Hopac
    nuget NodaTime
    nuget Expecto
    nuget Expecto.BenchmarkDotNet
```

Here's the PR/code in full https://github.com/logary/logary/pull/323

Comment: Could you please create an issue in the tracker? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER
For now (2018.1), Rider doesn't have "smart" restore for Paket, only "usual" NuGet dependencies are optimized for restore.

Comment: But since nothing has changed, paket's restore should be a noop. So it shouldn't be the responsibility of the dev env to track dependencies, don't you think?

Comment: I agree. However, Rider shouldn't restore packages if nothing is changed. I should check who is responsible for Paket restore: Rider or .NET Core SDK.